# How come distilled water hasn't replaced transformer oil as a high voltage insulator?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, dielectric, dielectric-breakdown

I've noticed that distilled water has an extremely high dielectric straight (65-70 MV/m).

With that considered, how come it isn't used in the place of transformer oil for 10-20 kV applications where the structure might not need to last multiple decades?

Comment: what is the dielectric strength of contaminated water?

Comment: It doesn't stay distilled for very long when in contact with a conductor

Comment: @ScottSeidman: short as it is, that's the answer.  You should post it as such.

Comment: Besides what @ScottSeidman said: It is mostly present to cool the transformer. Water has a much, much lower boiling point.

Comment: Moisture is a transformer killer. They have silcagel in the breather. Even if te structure won't last for decades, the transformer will be mounted on second place.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič But won't the moisture issue only be due to the conductivity of normal water, not distilled?

Comment: What if the distilled water is mixed with glycol ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water is good for making coffee but in electronics over time, it causes rust , and rust particles cause static discharges which drastically reduces the breakdown voltage of the insulation.

Even epoxy coated stainless steel will eventually emit particles of  rust thru, enough to degrade water to cause partial discharge which detonates particles and evaporates the medium.  This can cascade like lightning to cause a massive explosion.  The same can occur in oil, but unlike water TFMR oil has a Dk of only 2 and can support anti-oxidizer additives.

Worse yet, the polar properties of water make capacitance and lower the self resonant frequency. H20 has a dielectric constant Dk= 80 or about 20x worse than oil lowering the impedance of coils and self-resonant frequency.

Oil also has the same pristine breakdown voltage or BDV of 75k/mm or 75MV/m but that comes at cost of post-processed pressured , high temp moisture and particle removal to the parts per billion level so regulator transformer oil only must pass 25kV/mm and higher levels require in plant contamination removal equipment worth >$50k.

So if you don't mind the creapage effects in contaminated water, reducing the breakdown voltage from 70kV/mm to 1kV/mm go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Distilled water can't conduct electricity, that means it can't be a threat but it can't be used in cooling transformers because of the low boiling point, low dialectric, and it can also cause rust.

Comment: And don't forget that distilled water won't stay distilled for long, it's a mild solvent and will pick up ions if it comes into contact with metals, salts or other materials, then become conductive